# JQuery load php - php file without the template

Tags: jquery, templates, page-template

I'm about to start writing a php file that will return a JSON array to be used as a JQuery autocomplete source.

I want to create my source.php file that loads without the WordPress template.

Currently /includes/source.php contains:

```
<?php
echo "hello world";
?>
```

But if I go to http://www.mywordpress.com/includes/source.php I instead get the templated 404 page.

How can I avoid this?

EDIT

in response to the comments, here is my htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: It seems like to me you have a problem with your `.htaccess` file. You should add it to your answer so we can see it.

Comment: There's a page on the Codex-wiki about [using Ajax in plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) - you should check it out.

Comment: You can ordinarily get to particular `.php` files with a complete path like that. I also suspect something in the `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I've edited my question to include the htaccess file.

Comment: is includes in your theme directory, or the root of your site? if you want this to be portable and follow WordPress best-practices, you should read the AJAX link above.

Comment: Yes the includes is in the theme folder, so wp-content/mytheme/includes and wp-content/mytheme/js

Comment: well that's why you get a 404, the path should be http://www.mywordpress.com/wp-content/mytheme/includes/source.php, however, if you just hardcode the path to the file and load it directly you won't have access to any WordPress functions. I suggest going through the AJAX codex page and using the method outlined there to include your js file and enable your autocomplete function within the context of the WordPress environment.

Comment: That's great, Milo.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you use Wordpress ajax hooks. It is really simple.

first call the function from javascript or jQuery use the key as 'action' and value as 'function hook name'

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

var data = {
    action: 'my_action', // here is the function name
    whatever: 1234  // if there are the data you want to pass 
};

// since 2.8 ajaxurl is always defined in the admin header and points to admin-ajax.php
jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
    alert('Got this from the server: ' + response.first_name +' '+response.last_name);
});
});
```

Then you need to create the ajax hook in function.php

```
//wp_ajax is the prefix of the hooks and follow with your action name
add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback');   //this line is for logged in users
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action_callback'); // this is for not logged in users
```

Then write your own function here and return the result with json format in function.php just underneath or above the ajax hook.

```
function my_action_callback(){
      $data = array(
                 'first_name' => 'foo',
                 'last_name'  => 'bar'
              );
     return json_encode($data); 
     die; // you need to die otherwise you will see extra zero in your result because Wordpress automatically insert zero to make sure you stop the function here
}
```

I hope you are happy to use this way. It is easy and quick.

If you want to read more http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.  Not that I understand the full path, and how to add in the javascript, I should be able to progress.  Thanks again :)